# JSON JQuery & Morris Chart

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, morris.js

I'm trying to use the setData() function for a morris chart but I'm having some problems using json data.

Without setData(), this works perfect...

```
        if ($('#morris-area-graph').length > 0) {
        var labelColor = $('#morris-area-graph').css('color');
        var Chart = Morris.Area({
            element: 'morris-area-graph',
            behaveLikeLine: true,
            data: [
                {"x":"1:00am","y":"5.5"},{"x":"2:00am","y":"4.2"}

            ],
            xkey: 'x',
            parseTime: false,

            ykeys: ['y'],
            labels: ['Glucose Level'],
            gridTextColor: labelColor,
            lineColors: $('#morris-area-graph').data('colors').split(',')
        });
    }
```

This doesn't work at all...

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://url/jsontest.php",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);

            Chart.setData(result);
        }
    });

    // Morris Area demo
    if ($('#morris-area-graph').length > 0) {
        var labelColor = $('#morris-area-graph').css('color');
        var Chart = Morris.Area({
            element: 'morris-area-graph',
            behaveLikeLine: true,
            data: [
                {"x":"1:00am","y":"5.5"},{"x":"2:00am","y":"4.2"}

            ],
            xkey: 'x',
            parseTime: false,

            ykeys: ['y'],
            labels: ['Glucose Level'],
            gridTextColor: labelColor,
            lineColors: $('#morris-area-graph').data('colors').split(',')
        });
    }
```

As demonstrated above, taking the string of json that the php file outputs and inserting it into the data : [  ] part of the morris chart, works perfect.  However using the setData function, i get undefined points and the graph doesnt display any of the data.

I can have the php file output the json as :

```
[{"x":"1:00am","y":"5.5"},{"x":"2:00am","y":"4.2"}]
```

or

```
{"x":"1:00am","y":"5.5"},{"x":"2:00am","y":"4.2"}
```

neither appear to work. however the second one works fine if it's in the data : [] statically as a string.

Comment: if your code like this .. you surly get an error `Chart is not defined` ... So before your code use `var Chart;` and then use `Chart = Morris.Area` without var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function doesn't parse JSON strings by default, which is probably the reason why your script is failing.

So, you either:

a) parse your JSON response manually:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://url/jsontest.php",
    success: function (result) {

        var data = JSON.parse( result );
        console.log(data);

        if ( data ) {
            Chart.setData(data);
        }

    }
});
```

... or, b) use [$.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) instead, which does parse JSON strings automatically:

```
$.getJSON(
    "http://url/jsontest.php",
    function (result) {

        console.log(result);
        Chart.setData(result);

    }
});
```